# How to find out top ranking websites?

Tags: search-engines, google-ranking, ranking

My client wants to publish his website advertisement in the top ranking websites. Therefore, I would like to know can we find out way that what are top ranking websites in his country.

Comment: Pro Webmasters FYI: This question is based on SEO therefore, I think I've placed the question in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well top ranking websites you can find out by doing Google searches within his country only by the niche terms that is revelant to his/her content. There is little point in advertising lady products on tech related websites as the majority of these sites will be men (no sexism intended, but fact) and because these are mostly men you're receive less clicks, less conversions. Your client should be focusing on websites that have a lot of traffic that will convert well, any other approach would be considered wasteful.

I assume that your customer wants sites that have plenty of traffic, while there is no real way to determine the actual level of this because you don't have access to their Anayltics accounts for unique customers you can predict it using > http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries which is most likely your best option.

Comment: Thank you for and I would like to ask you another question. Is there a possibility we can get the top websites statistics by business categories. For Example: What are the car selling websites in UK. Alexa website provide some statistics by Business category but not by country